# insert variable into database using php

Tags: php, sql

> 2000-10-01,2000-12-16,2000-11-17,2001-03-10,2001-09-10,2000-09-02,2000-11-02,2000-12-06,2000-11-02,2000-12-09,2000-12-01,2001-04-16.
>
> Gambardella, Matthew,Ralls, Kim,Corets, Eva,Corets, Eva,Corets,
>   Eva,Randall, Cynthia,Thurman, Paula,Knorr, Stefan,Kress,
>   Peter,O'Brien, Tim,O'Brien, Tim,Galos, Mike

i have this value in variable $date and $author.i want to insert it into database.
i have been trying using .

```
$sql = "insert into book values('','$author','{$date}') ";
```

Comment: So what is the problem

Comment: i am not able to insert all the data stored into $data and $author variable.

Comment: Are you getting any error. Like any *violation's* of constraint

Comment: you need to explode the string and insert the data into loop i guess.

Comment: @VR46 when i echo this variable it shows - 2000-10-01,2000-12-16,2000-11-17,2001-03-10,2001-09-10,2000-09-02,2000-11-02,2000-12-06,2000-11-02,2000-12-09,2000-12-01,2001-04-16. but when i insert it it shows 0000-00-00 .

Comment: @AmitShah i need to insert it into single coulmn , i have already implode it into single variable. $author = implode(',' , $author);

Comment: @ShivRoy in that case i think please add mysql_real_escape_string which will save the query failure in case of O'Brien, Tim,O'Brien these names.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you have are having connection to mysql database.

```
$date = 
"2000-10-01,2000-12-16,2000-11-17,2001-03-10,2001-09-10,2000-09-02,2000-11-02,2000-12-06,2000-11-02,2000-12-09,2000-12-01,2001-04-16";

$authors="Gambardella,Matthew,Ralls,Kim,Corets,Eva,Corets,Eva,Corets,Eva,Randall,Cynthia,Thurman,Paula,Knorr,Stefan,Kress,Peter,O'Brien,Tim,O'Brien,Tim,Galos,Mike";



 $sql = "insert into book values('','".mysql_real_escape_string($author)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."') ";
 echo mysql_query($sql);
```

The code above will insert all the data into the database.

Thanks

Comment: Mysql_* is deprecated

Comment: @ShivRoy can you please mark it as answer, also you can use mysqli_real_escape_string if you dont want to use deprecated function mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: Marking correct answer will help our community to easily look at correct answer and take correct action faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please try query like below.

```
$sql = "insert into book values('','".$author."','".$date."') ";
```

And please echo and exit your query and then run it in databse that's why you identify what is issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
    // check on your DB connection
    $connDB = new mysqli ( $db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name );  

    $date = array("2000-10-01","2000-12-16");
    $author = array("Gambardella","Ralls");
    $count = 0;

foreach ($dates as $date)
{
   $sql_insert = "INSERT into book(something, author, date) values(',','$date','$author[$count]')";
   mysqli_query ( $connDB, $sql_insert );
   $count ++ ;
}
mysqli_close($connDB);
?>
```

Comment: Change  the order of values

Comment: $date should be $dates